# Regex, match a word that starts with one of a range of letters

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to match a word that starts with a letter from `h` to `t` and ends with `ing` or `ed` like the word `learning`.  I tried

```
\\s[h-t]\\w+[ing[ed]]\\s
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
^[h-t].*(ing|ed)$
```

Comment: Thank you! If your string is "learn leaning" it will match the whole thing because the "." will match everything including the spaces. I think it should be [h-t]\\(w+)(ing|ed) it worked.